# How to generally translate a recursive program into an iterative one?

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

For example, it is relatively straight forward to translate pre- and in-order traversal of a BST from recursive to iterative. But post-order is harder.

Here is the original recursive BST traversal function:

Python 3

```
def traverse_rec(node):  # traversal of sub-tree at node.
    # pre-order work here:
    # print(node.val, end=' ')
    if node.lft:
        traverse_rec(node.lft)

    # in-order work here:
    print(node.val, end=' ')

    # post-order work here:
    # print(node.val, end=' ')
    if node.rt:
        traverse(node.rt),
```

I found some iterative versions of recursive functions (pre-, in-, post-order BST traverse) for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-postorder-traversal-using-stack/), but I am looking for an iterative implementation that follows [what the computer does with it's call stack](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~213/lectures/07-machine-procedures.pdf) so that I can just as easily convert post-order BST traversals, and, more generally convert recursive code to iterative. So a 'frame' should be pushed onto the frame stack each time a function is called which records where to continue execution on function return, as well as any variables needed by the calling function that might get changed by the called function. The frames are popped from the frame stack on function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recursive to iterative translation using a frame_stack:

```
def traverse_iter(node):
    # Iterative bst traversal. A (node, state) tuple is pushed onto frame_stack where a recursive call would occur.
    # state defines where to pick up the processing on return (on pop).
    # state: 0: Did not just return into this frame.
    #        1: Just returned from left child.
    #        2: Just returned from right child.
    # Only states 1 and 2 get pushed onto the frame_stack.
    # Generally, state would include any variables that are needed on return that get changed on the frame change
    # in addition to the program counter (pc).
    # Here, each node has all the data (val) needed, and state 1 or 2 acts as a pc to determine where to pick up
    # on return.
    frame_stack = []
    state = 0  # Didn't just return from a child(function call).
    while True:
        if node is None:    
            if frame_stack:  # Returning up recursion tree:
                node, state = frame_stack.pop()
            else:            # or completed traversal.
                break

        if state == 0:
            # Execute pre-order work here.
            #print(node.val, end=' ')
            if node.lft:  # Emmulate recursive call into left child.
                frame_stack.append((node, 1))
                node = node.lft
                continue

        if state == 0 or state == 1:
            # Execute in-order work here
            print(node.val, end=' ')

            if node.rt:
                frame_stack.append((node, 2))
                node = node.rt
                state = 0       # State to descend into child.
                continue

        # Returning from a right child or there was none:
        # Execute post-order work here.
        # print(node.val, end=' ')
        node = None     # finished with this node (and all below it).
```

Once I 'got it', I found it fairly straightforward to develop and understand the above, and it seems the pattern I used is generally extensible to any recursive to iterative translation as it is based on what the computer does. I basically translate a recursive function call into an update of variables that get changed into the new function (node to a child node here), and push their original values onto the frame stack (node here) along with the pc (state here); minimal supporting logic was added as needed.

I am wondering if someone can supply an example where the frame payload requires more than (node, state) to pick up from function return where we left off, or simplify my BST traversal (while keeping it pre-, in-, and post-order general).